# LINQ JOIN with 3 tables where two of them have many-to-one relations

Tags: c#, linq

Hy. I'm working on a query, which should join 3 tables like

- client - has ID - take his name
- banking - has clientid - take some data from bankDate to bankDate
- marketing - has clientid - take some data from marketDate to marketDate

code:

```
var totals = from client in _db.Clients
                join bank in _db.Banking on client.Id equals bank.ClientId
                where (client.Id == bank.ClientId  &&
                       DateTime.Compare(bank.BankDate, (DateTime) fromDate) >= 0 &&
                       DateTime.Compare(bank.BankDate, (DateTime) toDate) <= 0)
                join market in _db.Marketing on client.Id equals market.ClientId
                where (client.Id == market.ClientId && 
                       DateTime.Compare(market.MarketDate, (DateTime) fromDate) >= 0 &&
                       DateTime.Compare(market.MarketDate, (DateTime) toDate) <= 0)
                select new {client.Username, bank, market};
```

This algorithm doesn't provide successful join for the tables with many-to-one  relations.
Who has ever faced this problem and knows how to solve it? I'll be very appreciated for any help

Comment: The first condition on each of the “where” clause is redundant. Anything you don’t need remove it. Could you provide more info on “doesn’t provide successful join”?

Comment: What kind of problem you have faced? Those values you get are not acceptable?

Comment: The inner join condition will handle the first condition on each of the where clauses hence why I said it’s redundant.

Comment: I don't think the `where` statement is referencing the correct table. You may have to do another approach.

Comment: @Aominè What you mean?

Comment: @LabLab `client.Id equals bank.ClientId` should take care of the `where (client.Id == bank.ClientId)`

Comment: @12seconds Yeap, I know. But changing this won't solve the problem, right?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the `where` statement is not referencing the correct table.

Try this: (might be syntax error)

```
var totals = from client in _db.Clients
        join bank in _db.Banking.Where(x => DateTime.Compare(x.BankDate, (DateTime) fromDate) >= 0 &&
                DateTime.Compare(x.BankDate, (DateTime) toDate) <= 0) on client.Id equals bank.ClientId
        join market in _db.Marketing.Where(x => DateTime.Compare(x.MarketDate, (DateTime) fromDate) >= 0 &&
                DateTime.Compare(x.MarketDate, (DateTime) toDate) <= 0) on client.Id equals market.ClientId
        select new {client.Username, bank, market};
```

Comment: Well, I dont think that this is the problem, but ill try this, thanks

Answer (score 0):

By many-to-one I guess you are looking for left outer join, try this.

```
var totals = from client in _db.Clients
                         join bank in _db.Banking on client.Id equals bank.ClientId into banks
                         from bank in banks.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         where (client.Id == bank.ClientId &&
                                DateTime.Compare(bank.BankDate, (DateTime)fromDate) >= 0 &&
                                DateTime.Compare(bank.BankDate, (DateTime)toDate) <= 0)
                         join market in _db.Marketing on client.Id equals market.ClientId into markets
                         from market in markets.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         where (client.Id == market.ClientId &&
                                DateTime.Compare(market.MarketDate, (DateTime)fromDate) >= 0 &&
                                DateTime.Compare(market.MarketDate, (DateTime)toDate) <= 0)
                         select new { client.Username, bank, market };
```